# How do I turn on spell checking in Skype?

Tags: skype, spell-check

How do I turn on spell checking for skype.  iChat does it so I am keen to have it for Skype aswell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work?

> For those of you using Skype for Mac, you can switch on spell checking in instant messages by right-clicking the message box, and choosing **Spelling and Grammar > Check Spelling While Typing**

<sub><sup>[Source](http://getsatisfaction.com/skype/topics/skype_spell_checker)</sup></sub>

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows I would recommend Ursa Spell Checker. I use it for a few languages. It works automatically. Very useful prog

Comment: is it free to use .?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

```
Unfortunately, Skype doesn't have a spell checking feature available yet.
Maybe sometime in the future but I'm not holding my breath.
```

But you can use this tinyspell check program http://tinyspell.numerit.com/#download . its totally free.

Comment: Skype has now ?

Answer (score 0):

Skype uses spell check feature of Windows. To enable / disable you need to go to settings --> Change pc settings ---> pc and devices ---> typing  (W 8.1)