# Skype spellchecker

Tags: windows-7, skype, spell-check

I would like to know if it's possible to add a spell checker on Skype with an add on from Skype or with a 3rd party program that works on Skype as well. I have a spell checker on Chrome but obviously it doesn't apply on Skype as well and I can't see my grammar mistakes there.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I run Windows 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [thread on official skype forum](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/How-to-turn-on-spell-check-on-in-Skype-on-a-windows-ran-laptop/td-p/1721129), skype does not have the built-in spell checker. You will need a third party application of this.

### Assuming you run windows

try to look at

> [Ursa Spell Checker](http://ursa-spelling.com/)
>
> Ursa Spell Checker is a small program that allows you to check and
>   correct your spelling while chatting in Skype easily and quickly. It
>   allows you to avoid embarrassing spelling mistakes when using Skype
>   chat. Our program helps you to keep the respect of your friends,
>   partners and customers! Feel more confident writing without spelling
>   mistakes!

and

> [TinySpell](http://tinyspell.numerit.com/#download)
>
> Occasionally you need to check spelling in an application that does
>   not include a spelling checker and you don't want to launch your word
>   processor just for that. This is when tinySpell becomes handy. It is a
>   small utility that allows you to easily and quickly check and correct
>   the spelling in any Windows application.

### If you are on MAC

try to look at you OS default spell checking options. I am not an expert in this, but AFAIK, you can enable it and use it for skype

You mat also want to take a look at [this thread](https://superuser.com/q/166400/281154)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I'm using Ursa Spell Checker for now. Thanks for the help!